# Knowing the store of the purchased product

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore

I have a Magento 1.9 site with 2 stores. Both stores have different root categories.

Products of both categories are shared between both stores.

When a customer made a purchase, is there a way to know which store he bought the product from?

Thanks
Jaime

Answer (score 0):

The tables `sales_flat_order` has a column `store_id` where Magento saves the information you need.

So you have many ways to get that information. For example if you have a `Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order` object you can simply call `$order->getStoreId()` to get the store id for that specific order.

If you want to get the information from the database just use

```
select store_id from sales_flat_order where [put your condition here];
```